# In javafx apply css styles to only the top-level menus but not their sub-menus

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

In a javafx proj with fxml & css files for ui design & styling,
naturally there is a `MenuBar` containing a menu-tree like:

```
Edit
  |
  Copy
  Paste

View
  |
  ShowGrid
  Show
  Zoom
    |
    50%
    100%
```

Here `Edit` & `View` are top-level menus and `Zoom` is a submenu.

I want to style the top-level `Menu`s so in the css file I add things like:

```
.menu {
    -fx-pref-height: 36;
    -fx-background-radius: 4;
}
```

But it would also apply to the submenu `Zoom`.
Is there a way to distinguish them?

That is, to distinguish `Menu` objs directly under a `MenuBar` and those under some other `Menu` obj.

True that I could just use the fx:id and repeat the style body:

```
#menuEdit {
    -fx-pref-height: 36;
    -fx-background-radius: 4;
}
#menuView {
    -fx-pref-height: 36;
    -fx-background-radius: 4;
}
```

But that seems very ineffient and error-prone.

Comment: You could try "#menuEdit, #menuView{...}. The CSS equivalent you need is "not", but this is not implemented in JavaFx CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Try to use this CSS:

```
.menu-bar .container > .menu {
    -fx-pref-height: 36;
    -fx-background-radius: 4;
}
```

This CSS styles **only** the **direct** child menus of all menuBars. If you want to only style the direct menus of a single menuBar, you can use `#menuBarId .container > .menu { ... }`.

**Solution 2:**

You could try `#menuEdit, #menuView{...}`. The CSS equivalent you need is "not", but this is not implemented in JavaFx CSS.

Comment: Missing a `.container`.  `.menu-bar .container > .menu` works!

Comment: Great! I updated my answer!